# Using controllerAs in stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I use the following

```
controller: function() {
    this.name = 'Hank';
},
controllerAs: 'ctrl'
```

I can access name via `{{ ctrl.name }}`.

Although if use the following

```
controller: 'TestCtrl as ctrl'
```

where TestCtrl is

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function(...) {
    this.name = "Hank";
}
```

Accessing `{{ ctrl.name }}` yields nothing.

It was working before when I did not specify the controller in the state but in the html with

```
ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it worked when specifying controller in the html and when specifying controller as a function in the state but to get it to work with a string in the state all I had to do was

```
return this;
```

at the end of my controller.

I hope this helps some people and maybe someone knowledgeable can explain to me the reason why this happened.